# Getting 401 Unauthorized response when calling thru CloudFront endpoint

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, api-gateway

We have a setup wherein we put CloudFront in front of our Backend API (proxy).

All endpoints were ALMOST successful. POST requests went okay however, GET requests didn't.

-

**Calling the proxy:**

> POST https://proxy.api.com/add :: Response Successful!
>
> GET https://proxy.api.com/ping :: Response Successful!

**Calling thru CloudFront:**

> POST https://abc.cloudfront.net/add :: Response Successful!
>
> GET https://abc.cloudfront.net/ping :: 401 Unauthorized!

Any idea?

Comment: CloudFront strips and adds lot of things to a request, 401 is from the backend, can you check what information backend is expecting for authorization , e.g: Cloudfront bydefault strips authorization header.

Comment: That's new to me. Some POST requests require _x-api-key_ or _Authorization_ and GET requests require _Authorization_.

Comment: x-api-key is forwarded to origin by cloudfront , try to whitelist Authorization header and clear the cache to test again if it works.

Answer (score 3):

I found answers here [401 Unauthorized!](https://dev.to/dvddpl/basic-auth-on-lambda-api-gateway-cloudfront-solving-the-401-unauthorized-error-hif)

**Problem:**

GET requests Cloudfront removes the Authorization header field before forwarding the request to the origin. (see docs) [aws doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#request-custom-headers-behavior)

GET and HEAD requests – CloudFront removes the Authorization header field before forwarding the request to your origin.

OPTIONS requests – CloudFront removes the Authorization header field before forwarding the request to your origin if you configure CloudFront to cache responses to OPTIONS requests.

DELETE, PATCH, POST, and PUT requests – CloudFront does not remove the header field before forwarding the request to your origin.

**How to fix:**

From UI Console go to Cache Behaviour Setting and Edit
select Whitelist under Cache Based on Selected Request and then add Authorization under Whitelist Headers

[cloudfront](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2NgT.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is because path ping/* is not able to access origin

Solution is to add this path in behavior to disable cache and all go to origin

[image]

Comment: This saved me from a ton of extra "problems"! I had issues with WordPress rest API and got 401's back for some URI's and the "add header" trick didn't work. 
Adding a new "behaviour" for /wp-json/* with disabled cache and "AllViewer" did the trick as @timtike suggests!
The new AWS CloudFront console looks a bit different but the naming are similar to the screen grab above!

Answer (score 1):

I received this error when attempting to set a user/password on an amplify domain.

(2023 Answer)

1. In your cloudfront distribution navigate to the `Behaviors` tab and click edit
2. Under `cache key and origin requests` add a legacy cache setting
3. Add the header, `Authorization`
4. Save changes

You should now be able route to your page without the 401 error.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved the rest of my night :D After the change login in my app works correctly!